# Stacked Area in D3.js

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js, charts

I'm using D3.js and I'm having trouble setting up a stacked layout for an area chart with multiple series.  I have two possible structures of my data (if that helps).  One is the raw data fed to the script, in this structure:

```
var data = [{key: 'Group1', value: 37, date: '04/23/12'},
           {key: 'Group2', value: 12, date: '04/23/12'},
           {key: 'Group3', value: 46, date: '04/23/12'},
           {key: 'Group1', value: 32, date: '04/24/12'},
           {key: 'Group2', value: 19, date: '04/24/12'},
           {key: 'Group3', value: 42, date: '04/24/12'},
           {key: 'Group1', value: 45, date: '04/25/12'},
           {key: 'Group2', value: 16, date: '04/25/12'},
           {key: 'Group3', value: 44, date: '04/25/12'},
           {key: 'Group1', value: 24, date: '04/26/12'},
           {key: 'Group2', value: 52, date: '04/26/12'},
           {key: 'Group3', value: 64, date: '04/26/12'}]
```

Second is a nested structure, created using this code:

```
 pData = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.key; })
            .map(data);
```

Resulting in this structure:

```
pData = {Group1: [{date: 04/23/12, key: "Group1", value: 37}, 
                  {date: 04/24/12, key: "Group1", value: 32}, 
                  {date: 04/25/12, key: "Group1", value: 45},
                  ...],
         Group2: [{date: 04/23/12, key: "Group2", value: 12},
                  {etc, etc, etc}],
         GroupX: [...] }
```

**My questions is**: How do I setup a `d3.layout.stack()` generator, using one of the above data structures (or some variation), to create a stacked structure for my data such that I can pass it to an area generator similar to this:

```
var areaGenerator = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate('monotone')
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(h)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must feed an array of layers to the stack layout, so the first thing to change is to use [nest.entries](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-nest_entries) rather than [nest.map](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-nest_map). This returns an array of objects with a `key` field (such as "Group1") and a `values` array which contains the associated records. You would then specify a [stack.values](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#wiki-values) accessor so that the stack layout can access the `values` array for each layer.

You will also need to define suitable *x* and *y* accessors to the stack layout so that it can understand your input data: the *x*-accessor should return `d.date`, and the *y*-accessor should return `d.value`. You will also need to convert your date strings to Dates; you can use [d3.time.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) to help with this. For example:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y");
data.forEach(function(d) { d.date = format.parse(d.date); });
```

Lastly, change your area definition so that the baseline y0 is defined as `y(d.y0)` and the topline y1 is defined as `y(d.y0 + d.y)`.

Here's a working example:

- http://bl.ocks.org/3020685

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Worth pointing out to Javascript noobs (like me!) that the + before the d.value (in the data callback) converts to a number - see [here](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/).

In the callback, how are y0 values assigned? I used [this](http://pastebin.com/amjkBRYV) code to inspect, and got [this](http://i.imgur.com/lQFyJNL.png) output.

Each object is logged twice - before and after editing. Before, it only contains data from the csv - afterwards, it has a "y0=0", as I set, but (when drilling down in Chrome) also a y, and a non-zero y0. What's going on there?

Comment: (For reference, I'm trying to manipulate the y0 value so that the graph displays cumulative totals, rather than values at each point)

Sorry if you get multiple notifications for my previous edits - not used to StackOverflow style, made some mistakes!